# Access VBA - Format excel column to General using TextToColumns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to format a column in excel using TextToColumns in access vba. I'd like to format the column (which contain dates in excel) to General format. I don't encounter an error when the code is ran, but the format of the column doesn't change.

Excerpt of the code where formatting is run is given below:

```
Dim rng as Range
    set rng= oWS.Range("AD:AD")
        rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xlFixedWidth,FieldInfo:=Array(0, xlGeneralFormat)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi mccoydo:  I am not sure what the most efficient way to do this is, but by adding the statement `rng.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"` I was able to change the format of a range.

In your code, the argument `xlGeneralFormat` looks suspicious and there might be an alternative that gets you desired result in one fell swoop.